# What is the idea in this bash statement ( command || true )?

Tags: bash

I saw the following bash statement being used on the internet:

```
PYTHON_BIN_PATH=$(which python || which python3 || true)
```

I understand that if `which python` fails, then `which python3` will be executed, but I don't understand the purpose of the `true` at the end of the condition. Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try running:(Note the **bla**)

```
which python_bla || which python3_bla_bla || true
echo $?
0
```

You will get `RC=0`. It means it a construct to successfully proceed to next command. Here we know `python_bla` or `python3_bla_bla` does not exist,but still command gave `rc=0`
Example: Check the RC of following three commands, I have changed the spelling of `date` command to incorrect but `true` is causing `RC` to remain `0`.

```
date;echo $?
Thu Nov  9 01:40:44 CST 2017
0
datea;echo $?
If 'datea' is not a typo you can use command-not-found to lookup the package that contains it, like this:
    cnf datea
127
datea||true;echo $?
If 'datea' is not a typo you can use command-not-found to lookup the package that contains it, like this:
    cnf datea
0
```

Note: You can also use `:` operator instead of true to get the same results.Example:

```
command || :
```

Answer (score 1):

To be more rigorous I guess.

for example:

if `aaa` isn't an existed global binary file.
After executing `which aaa`,you can execute `echo $?` and the result is `1`.

But if you execute `which aaa | true` the result will be `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Simple. It will check either your system has out of the box python(version of python which has come with your O.S) or it has python version 3 in it. It will also confirm python's executable path too, you could simply print variable named `PYTHON_BIN_PATH` by doing `echo "$PYTHON_BIN_PATH"` and could check it too once.

***EDIT:*** Here is a simple example to understand. Let's say we have a variable named `val` with NULL value and we do this:

```
echo $val || true
```

Output will be NULL then as it's previous command didn't give any output.
Let's say we have `val=4` then we run it as follows.

```
val="4"
echo $val || true
4
```

Comment: Yeah, but I asked about the `true`.

Comment: Doesn't `which python` tells that? the python version

Answer (score -1):

The idea is to set the `PYTHON_BIN_PATH` to nothing if both `which` fails.

Visibly there is no difference between

```
PYTHON_BIN_PATH=$(which python || which python3 || true)
```

and

```
PYTHON_BIN_PATH=$(which python || which python3)
```

But running the command alone makes things more obvious. Suppose that python doesn't exist on the system.

```
$(which python || which python3)
echo $? #Returning the exit status of the previous command
1 # A non zero status generally means the previous statement failed
$(which python || which python3 || true)
echo $?
0
```

In short, using `true` at the end always give a zero exit status for

```
 $( command || true )
```